# Can negative autocorrelation at lags 1 and 2 happen?

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation

Just doing a couple of mind games going through my stats notes...

I've seen ACFs around with negative values at lags 1 and 2 - I might be having a mind blank here, but wouldn't a high negative AC at lag 1 imply a series like (-1,1,-1,1,...), and as such we'd be expecting the AC to alternate between positive and negative as well?

If I'm completely wrong here - is there an easy made up example where we have strong negative AC for both lags 1 and 2?

Thank you!

Comment: (+1) This is closely related to questions about the positive-definiteness of covariance matrices: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=covariance%20three%20positive%20definite.  That condition imposes constraints on how negative the ACF can get simultaneously at lags 1 and 2.

Answer (score 4):

The following DGP, an MA($2$) process, has negative autocorrelation at lags 1 and 2:

$$
Y_t=10-.5\cdot u_{t-1}-.25\cdot u_{t-2}+u_t
$$

Here's some R code to simulate the DGP and see the ACF for yourself:

```
library(stats)
library(forecast) # for the Acf() function

# number of "observations"
n<-500 
# initialization periods
j<-1000

# choose parameters
alpha<-10
theta<-c(-.5,-.25)
Q<-length(theta)

# generate iid disturbances
u<-rnorm(n+j,0,2)

# define the DGP and generate data series iteratively
y<-rep(alpha,n+j)
for(k in (Q+1):(n+j)){
  y[k]<-alpha + sum(theta*u[k-c(1:Q)]) + u[k] 
}

# get rid of the initialization periods
Y<-y[-c(1:j)]

# confirm the parameters
arima(Y,c(0,0,Q))

#   Call:
#   arima(x = Y, order = c(0, 0, Q))
#   
#   Coefficients:
#             ma1      ma2  intercept
#         -0.4763  -0.2546     9.9979
#   s.e.   0.0448   0.0485     0.0246
#   
#   sigma^2 estimated as 4.124:  log likelihood = -1064.03,  aic = 2134.05

# look at the ACF/PACF
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
Acf(Y)
pacf(Y)
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Good example. A few typos though? Should it be `y<-rep(0,n+j)` and `acf` instead of `Acf`? Also `library(stats)` just in case someone doesn't know.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I've added the libraries. The `acf()` function is from the forecast package, which I like to use because it omits lag 0 = 1 from the graph. I put `a` in the `y<-rep(a,n+j)` line for consistency, so that the initial values of `y` were set to its unconditional mean, but because there are no AR terms, it doesn't matter what values are stored there before the loop (they'll get over written anyways).

Comment: `y<-rep(a,n+j)` is indeed a typo! I meant it to be `y<-rep(alpha,n+j)`

Comment: A similar example: if non-stationary processes are allowed then you can have negative autocorrelation at all lags. For example, $y_1=1$, $y_n = -(0.5)^{n-2}$ for $n \ge 2$.